# How to apply jquery function for each article

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a DOM-like this. I have a jquery function that checks if there is a class "visible" into the article, remove it and add it on the clicked "hotspot" class. This function has to work for-each "article" independently from the others. I create this function but it doesn't work:

```js
$("article").each(function() {
  $("article .hotspot").on("touchstart", function() {
    $(".hotspot.visible").not(this).removeClass('visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');
  })
})
```

```html
<article>
  <div class="hotspot">
    <div class="hotspot">
</article>

<article>
  <div class="hotspot">
    <div class="hotspot">
</article>
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: what does not work?

Comment: change this `$("article .hotspot")` to `$(this).find(".hotspot")`

Comment: no reason to use the .each function here

Comment: @ArunKumar i'm afraid that it shouldn't be changed

Comment: for each article function has to be used independently. In this situation if i click on "hotspot" class in one article, this class will be deleted on every article in the DOM. I want to limit the action only to the article in object.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/Lojts52f/ Use jQuery's `closest()` or `siblings()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem will be solved if you remove the `.each()` loop, check the explanation below.

**Explanation:**

Since you loop using the `.each()` method, in every iteration the event will be attached, in your case you've two `article's` so the event will be attached twice to every item and then it will be fired two times when trigger `touchstart`.

Then because you're using `toggleClass()` the first event will add or remove the class then the second one will do the opposite and it'll look like the event isn't fired at all.

```js
$("article .hotspot").on("touchstart click", function() {
  $(this).parent().find(".hotspot.visible").not(this).removeClass('visible');
  $(this).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

```css
.visible {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div class="hotspot">1</div>
  <div class="hotspot">2</div>
</article>
<br>
<article>
  <div class="hotspot">1</div>
  <div class="hotspot">2</div>
</article>
```

**NOTE:** To check the behavior that I've explained you can see the `console.log('Event fired')` inside the event was triggered two times on click.

```js
$("article").each(function() {
  $("article .hotspot").on("touchstart click", function() {
    $(".hotspot.visible").not(this).removeClass('visible');
    $(this).toggleClass('visible');

    console.log('Event fired');
  })
})
```

```css
.visible {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div class="hotspot">1</div>
  <div class="hotspot">2</div>
</article>

<article>
  <div class="hotspot">1</div>
  <div class="hotspot">2</div>
</article>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I want that background color must be at the same time in the first and second article. Not in only one

Comment: Then you need to add the active class to the parent, check my update.

Comment: Nope. I want to add class on the child tag with class "hotspot". For each article I want to add class on only one "hotspot" child.

Comment: Thank you!! Only one question. Can you explain what does this code? 
    $(this).parent().find(".hotspot.visible").not(this).removeClass('visible');

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181478/discussion-between-andrew-and-zakaria-acharki).

Answer (score 0):

this should work for you

```
$("article .hotspot").on("touchstart", function() {
    $("article .hotspot").removeClass('visible');
    $(this).addClass('visible');
});
```

or

```
$("article .hotspot").on("click", function() {
    $("article .hotspot").removeClass('visible');
    $(this).addClass('visible');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```js
$("article").each(function() {
   $(this).children('.hotspot').on("touchstart click", function(){
       $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');     
   })
})
```

```css
article .hotspot.active{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<article>
  <div class="hotspot">1</div>
 <div class="hotspot">2</div>
</article>
<br>
<article>
 <div class="hotspot">1</div>
 <div class="hotspot">2</div>
</article>
```

If you want to have more than one active hotspot selected, then remove:

```
$(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
```

and change:

```
$(this).addClass('active');
```

for

```
$(this).toggleClass('active');
```